# Docker stopped working: Failed to install symlinks in /usr/local/bin (stage 4)

Tags: docker

All of a sudden today Docker on my Mac stopped working with a 'failed to install symlinks"

I tried to get back to a clean state by uninstalling Docker and trying to remove all symlinks in the /usr/local/bin. I'm left with two simlinks docker-compose and docker-machine that I cannot remove even with sudo.

Any suggestion on how to delete those files (that I suspect are the root of the problem) so I can do a clean install?

Not sure if helps but 'Macfee Endpoint security' is running on my Mac.

Comment: can mention cmd for removing symlink and what error you getting while removing?

Comment: sudo rm, rm, unlink,... Nothing work always permission denied

Comment: Weirdly, Docker didn't complain about any particular symlink for me, and starting Docker again and all my containers the exact same as before works fine. This error only occurred after my Mac went to sleep and logged me out. Seems like a bug.

Answer (score 3):

I recently have the same problem on my mac.

I resolved it by changing the owner of `/usr/local/bin` by the current user like that:

`# sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin`

Comment: I'm already owner of the folder and all files so this didn't help me :(

Comment: Maybe could you, as said in one of the other response of this thread, restart your computer to reindex your symlinks.

Answer (score 2):

This is possibly a broken symlink. Please use this command to find if it’s pointing to an existing parent file:

```
# ls -lh file
```

From the output of the command above, if it points to broken parent file, then force the removal of that file first as root:

```
# rm -rf <broken-referenced-file>
```

And then unlink the binary symlinks:

```
# unlink <file>
```

Also make sure there is no running process related to docker and that no open files are being held by any docker associated process. To get a list of open files do this:

```
# lsof | grep deleted
# lsof | grep -i docker 
# lsof | grep deleted | grep -i docker
```

Compare the outputs to see if there are any for docker; if so, kill the process using:

```
# kill -SIGKILL <PID>
```

And again try unlinking.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exact same problem this morning ... but instead of jumping straight into file deletion I restarted my mac and all is well again.

Just saying that more often than not a reboot can fix many problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I find bin some what messed in /usr/local/bin. I took a backup of /usr/local/bin and deleted it and recreate new directory /usr/local/bin with same permissions. Then it worked.